# Algebraic extensions most general form

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

Let's say you have a field $E$ and a subfield $F$ of $E$.
Consider now the field extension $F(S)$ where $S = \{s_1, s_2, ..., s_n\}$.

How do elements of $F(S)$ look like, as in what is their most general form?

Comment: $$F(S)= \{ p(s_1, \dots , s_n) : p \in F[X_1, \dots , X_n] \}$$

Comment: In addition to the previous comment, if some elements in $S$ are transcendental over $F$ we need to consider rational expressions in $s_1,\dots,s_n$, i.e. the elements are of the form $p(s_1,\dots,s_n)/q(s_1,\dots,s_n)$ where $p,q\in F[X_1,\dots,X_n]$.